# Saving a HashMap piece by piece to File

Tags: java, hashmap, save, export

I am running a large loop in **Java** where, in every pass, data is populated in a HashMap.
The loop is very long so I cannot hold the complete HashMap in memory. So I need to find a way to export the Hashmap to a file after every 1000 iterations or so.

I was thinking about exporting the HashMap using serialization after every 1000 steps to a file, clearing the HashMap variable and repeating the process by appending the next to the same file. But the problem would then occur while retrieving the complete HashMap from the file as there would be metadata appended to the file every time I export. So is there any other way to do this?

Edit:
The HashMap structure is given below:

```
    HashMap<Key, double[]>

    Key {
        String name;
        BitSet set;
    }
```

Comment: What metadatas would you need in case you go for the serialization?

Comment: The purpose of the continuously growing Map is not clear, but assuming it is needed  on every loop consider using a database (instead of a file) to hold the key/values.  Maybe have a LFU cache to avoid hitting the database on every loop.

Comment: @alainlompo If I serialize and save I need to save to a new file every time I do. If I keep appending to the same file I can only retrieve the first object. I'm assuming that's because while saving the first time, some metadata was attached to the beginning of the file that said that this file contains one HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have a great idea of clearing the file every N amount of iterations, which would look something similar to this:

```
public void exportHashTable() {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("hi", "world");

    for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {

        // Some logic ..

        if (i % 1000 == 0) {
            appendToFile(map);
            map.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

In order to import **you don't have to read the entire file, but read it line by line**, in case you exported it (not serialized it). Let's say you export it as `CSV` or maybe even `JSON`. In that case, you can import the HashMap and process N amount of rows, then clear and proceed further.

```
public void importHashTable() {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // process the line, add to hashmap or do some other operation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but what my question is, is how do I implement appendToFile? Because using serialization does not work. Is there some function in Java to export HashMap to a CSV or JSON? (without downloading any new libraries)

Comment: Yeah, there are libraries that convert an object to JSON (Jackson and Gson) and there are libraries for creating CSV like Apache Commons. Unfortunately, you did not provide any objects that you are saving that I use to show you an example, however, if you edit the post and provide me with an example of an object you are trying to save and ask me in comments to this answer I would gladly do.

Comment: added the example